# fancybox click link within javascript

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have a fancybox setup that works when a link is clicked but I need to load the function from within javascript

The code/function I want to call is :

```
<a class="various iframe" href="https://maps.google.com/?output=embed&f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=London+Eye,+County+Hall,+Westminster+Bridge+Road,+London,+United+Kingdom&hl=lv&ll=51.504155,-0.117749&spn=0.00571,0.016512&sll=56.879635,24.603189&sspn=10.280244,33.815918&vpsrc=6&hq=London+Eye&radius=15000&t=h&z=17">Google maps (iframe)</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the value of the text field and append it into the popup? Like so? -

```
var longitude = $('#longitude').val();

$("#info_text").text(longitude);
```

Comment: Yes thats what I am trying to do but I cant!! I have tried everything I can think of, thanks